# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero issue, TypeError: 'module' object isnt callable

Tags: python

Im trying to learn Hohmann Transfer using Python, and ran into and issue, that look something like this

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Family\Documents\Hohmann.py", line 32, in 
sc0, sc1, sc_transfer, delta_vs=t.hohmann_transfer(coes0=coes0,coes1=coes1,propagate=True)
File "C:\Users\Family\Documents\Tools.py", line 138, in hohmann_transfer
sc0=SC(coes0,T0,dt,coes=True,output_dir=os.path.join(output_dir,names[0]))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Edit: Solved the previous error, now getting another error (TypeError: 'module' object is not callable)

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    import time
    import datetime
    import os
    import math
    from decimal import Decimal
    import Spacecraft as SC
    
    import planetary_data as pd
    
    d2r=np.pi/180
    
    
    def plot_n_orbits(rs,labels,cb=pd.Earth,show_plot=False,save_plot=False,title='Orbits'):
        fig=plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
        ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
    
        #Plot trajactory
        n=0
        for r in rs:
            ax.plot(r[:,0],r[:,1],r[:,2],label=labels[n])
            ax.plot([r[0,0]],[r[0,1]],[r[0,2]])
            n+=1
    
        #Plot central body
        _u,_v=np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j,0:np.pi:10j]
        _x=cb['Radius']*np.cos(_u)*np.sin(_v)
        _y=cb['Radius']*np.sin(_u)*np.sin(_v)
        _z=cb['Radius']*np.cos(_v)
        ax.plot_surface(_x,_y,_z,cmap='Blues')
    
        #Plot the xyz vectors
        l=cb['Radius']*2
        x,y,z=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
        u,v,w=[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
        ax.quiver(x,y,z,u,v,w,color='k')
    
        max_val=np.max(np.abs(rs))
    
        ax.set_xlim([-max_val,max_val])
        ax.set_ylim([-max_val,max_val])
        ax.set_zlim([-max_val,max_val])
    
        ax.set_xlabel(['X(km)'])
        ax.set_ylabel(['Y(km)'])
        ax.set_zlabel(['Z(km)'])
    
        #def write_2d_array(arr,name):-
        #def read_2d_array(filename):-
        #def rv2ap(r,v,mu=pd.Earth['mu']):-
        
    def hohmann_transfer_scalars(r0,r1,altitude=True,cb=pd.Earth):
        #If passing in altitude that is not semi major axis
        if altitude:
    
            #Add central body radius to r values
            r0+=cb['Radius']
            r1+=cb['Radius']
    
        #Caiculate semimajor axis of trans orbit
        a_transfer=(r0+r1)/2.0
    
        #Calculate circular orbits velocities
        v_circ_init=math.sqrt(cb['mu']/r0)
        v_circ_final=math.sqrt(cb['mu']/r1)
    
        #Calculate initial & final trans orbit velocities(vis-viva)
        v0_transfer=math.sqrt( cb['mu']*(2/r0-1/a_transfer))
        v1_transfer=math.sqrt( cb['mu']*(2/r1-1/a_transfer))
    
        #Calculate transfer time (half a period)
        t_transfer=math.pi*math.sqrt(a_transfer**3/cb['mu'])
    
        #Calculate delta V values
        delta_vs=[abs(v0_transfer-v_circ_init),abs(v_circ_final-v1_transfer)]
    
        return delta_vs,t_transfer
    
    def hohmann_transfer(
                            r0=0,r1=0,cb=pd.Earth,coes0=[],coes1=[],altitude=True,
                            propagate=False,dt=100,
                            output_dir='',names=['Initial','Final','Transfer'],write_output=False
                        ):
    
        #Check if coes passed in
        if coes0:
            #Extract r0 and r1
            r0=coes0[0]
            r1=coes1[0]
    
        #If passing in altitude that is not semimajor axis
        elif altitude:
    
            #Add central body radius to r values
            r0+=cb['Radius']
            r1+=cb['Radius']
    
        #Calculate semimajor axis of trans orbit
        a_transfer=(r0+r1)/2.0
    
        #Calculate velocities of circular orbits
        v_circ_init=math.sqrt(cb['mu']/r0)
        v_circ_final=math.sqrt(cb['mu']/r1)
    
        #Calculate initial and final trans orbits velocities(vis-viva)
        v0_transfer=math.sqrt( cb['mu']*(2/r0-1/a_transfer))
        v1_transfer=math.sqrt( cb['mu']*(2/r1-1/a_transfer))
    
        #Calculate transfer time(half a period)
        t_transfer=math.pi*math.sqrt(a_transfer**3/cb['mu'])
    
        #Calculate delta V values
        delta_vs=[v0_transfer-v_circ_init,v_circ_final-v1_transfer]
    
        #Propagate orbits
        if propagate:
    
            #If coes not passed in
            if not coes0:
    
                #Create coes lists
                coes0=[r0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
                coes1=[r1,0.0,0.0,180.0,0.0,0.0]
    
            #Calculate eccentricity of transfer orbit
            e_transfer=1-r0/a_transfer
    
            #Coes for trans orbit
            coes_transfer=[a_transfer,e_transfer,coes0[2],0.0,coes0[4],coes0[5]]
    
            #Calculate periods of initial and final orbits
            T0=2*np.pi*(r0**3/cb['mu'])**0.5
            T1=2*np.pi*(r1**3/cb['mu'])**0.5
    
            #Create spacecraft instances & propagate orbits
            sc0=SC(coes0,T0,dt,coes=True,output_dir=os.path.join(output_dir,names[0]))
            sc1=SC(coes1,T1,dt,coes=True,output_dir=os.path.join(output_dir,names[1]))
            sc_transfer=SC(coes_transfer,t_transfer,dt,coes=True,output_dir=os.path.join(output_dir,names[2]))
    
            #Write ouput files
            if write_output:
                sc0.write_traj()
                sc1.write_traj()
                sc_transfer.write_traj()
    
            return sc0,sc1,sc_transfer,delta_vs
        return delta_vs,t_transfer
        
            
    
        #ax.set_aspect('equal')
    
        ax.set_title(title)
        plt.legend()
    
        if show_plot:
            plt.show()
        if save_plot:
            plt.savefig(title+'.png',dpi=300)



    
    
Apologies for all these questions. Im still a noob and have no one else to ask, apart from forums like these.



Apologies for all the noob questions im struggling to learn all of this by myself and the only help i can hopefully get is from forums like these.
```

Comment: check if r1 isn't 0

Comment: You have a typo `r1+coes1[0]`, I assume you wanted to assign it like `r0` in the line above it?

Comment: Don't include text/code as an image in your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: You should copy/paste your code to the question, not provide a link to the picture.

Comment: Apologies, will paste the code ASAP. Was not aware image sharing is frowned upon. Will not do so again

Comment: @shriakhilc YES that was it crap how did i mis that.....really need to keep my eyes open. Thank you

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).